# Implementing distinct functionality in Oracle discoverer

Tags: oracle, business-intelligence

I have a column like

```
Column
a1
a1
a1
a2
a2
a2
a2
```

In Oracle Discoverer, How to make it

```
Column
a1
a2
```

How to implement the "distinct" functinality in oracle discoverer report

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Discvoerer Plus, in the "Edit Worksheet" dialog box, select the "Table Layout" tab. Click on the "Hide Duplicate Rows" check box. This results in the sql changing from a select to a select distinct.